# function is called as a non function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website needs to convert its nav menu when it is in a viewport which size is less than 800px.More over I have made a plugin for this and that plugin also provide vertical nav options.So i want to apply that vertical nav when it is in viewport less than 800px.

**My codes for vertical nav**

```
if(verticalNav){
   menuConvert()
}
```

**And when in less than 800px**

```
if($(window).width < 800){
   menuConvert()
}
```

**And menuConvert function is**

```
var menuConvert = function(){
     // codes here
}
```

But in console log: `menuConvert is not a function`

Any solution for that?

Comment: CSS media queries will be better for this @media screen and(max-width:800px){ //put your style in here; }

Comment: I think the problem is `var menuConvert = function(){` is executed after `menuConvert()` call

Comment: Are you loading your javascript file at the bottom of your `<body></body>` tags?

Answer (score 3):

```
var menuConvert = function(){
     // codes here
}
```

should be PLACED above

```
if($(window).width < 800){
 menuConvert();
}
```

OR change assignment to simple `function` like this:

```
function menuConvert(){
   console.log("Hello")
}
```

and it should work. The reason is *JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations*.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript there is a difference between

```
var a = function() { ... };
```

and

```
function a() { ... }
```

The first is an assignment and is executed where the statement is met during the normal execution flow. This means for example that you cannot call `a()` **before** it has been set to be a function/closure.

The second is instead a function declaration and for example code like

```
console.log(b());
function b() { return 42; }
```

is valid.